# Why does usage of Option.get gives a compile error

Tags: scala

I want to filter out options which are not defined in a sequence and create sequence without Options(with the actual value). I am trying to compile the following code in scala :

```
val idLibId = idOptionalLibId.filter(idOptionalLibId => idOptionalLibId._2.isDefined)
.map(idLibId => idLibId._1 -> idLibId._2.get)
```

idOptionalLibId is Seq of tuples.

But it gives me the follownig error:

```
[error] MandatoryApprovalOverride.scala:27:55: Use of Option.get
[error]             .map(idLibId => (idLibId._1 -> idLibId._2.get))
[error]
```

Anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `.get` on an `Option` is dangerous because it will throw if the value is `None`. You know that you've filtered all the `None` values out but the compiler doesn't.

Wouldn't this be a better way to do it?

```
val idLibId = idOptionalLibId.collect{case (k,Some(v)) => k -> v}
```

Comment: That helped, thanks a lot. I am new to scala, so this was probably obvious question. I am wondering if `idOptionalLibId.collect{case (k,None) => k}` would then return sequence of values for which Option was empty. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct. That will return all the `tuple._1` values where `tuple._2` is `None`.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason this would be an error is due to settings of your particular project, e.g. a combination of [WartRemover](https://www.wartremover.org) to warn on `Option.get` and `-Xfatal-warnings` to turn all warnings into errors. You can see https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html for motivation:

> `scala.Option` has a `get` method which will throw if the value is `None`. The program should be refactored to use `scala.Option#fold` to explicitly handle both the `Some` and `None` cases.

and likely other cases where you'll run into similar warnings/errors (depending on WartRemover configuration in your project).

Though in this case the fix proposed by @jwvh is better than `fold` or `getOrElse`.